# Workaround for kramdown couldn't parse math blocks correctly when using Jekyll

Tags: markdown, kramdown

I encountered a problem with inline math rendering and demos can be found <s>[here](https://zhengyuan-public.github.io/posts/MathJaxProblems/)</s>. I originally thought Mathjax caused it, but after creating an issue [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/3103) and it turns out the default markdown engine kramdown actually caused the problem.

For example, there are two inline math blocks wrapped around `$` in the following markdown:

```markdown
For each RoI (also for each class), PS RoI pooling is applied to obtain *normalized* offsets $ \Delta \hat{p}_{i, j} $ and then transformed to the real offsets $ \Delta p_{i, j} $
```

When kramdown translates it into HTML, the text between two underscores, i.e., `{i, j} $, and then transformed to the real offsets $ \Delta p`, was converted into italic text before the HTML can be further rendered into math equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems a bug in the default markdown engine kramdown. I've found a workaround, but it has only been tested with [jekyll-theme-chirpy](https://github.com/cotes2020/jekyll-theme-chirpy). I'm not sure which version of kramdown is being used, so this might not work for a future version of kramdown.

The solution can be summarized as:

1. block math should be added with `$$ math $$` **with** a blank line **both before and after** `$$`.
2. inline math (normal) should be added with `$$ math $$` **without any** blank lines before or after `$$`.
3. inline math (in lists) should be added with `\$$ math $$`, which escapes the first `$`.

More details can be found on my GitHub page post
[here](https://zhengyuan-public.github.io/posts/PersonalBlogWithJekyll/#latex-math-equations-in-jekyll).